# How to generate Debug symbols with Makefile for C? [Linux]

Tags: c, linux, debugging, makefile, debug-symbols

I'm trying to use GDB and KDEvelop to debug a console app under Knoppix VM.
KDevelop and GDB don't break at my breakpoints. I suspect it's because they don't have debug symbols.

If I'm correct how do I need to change my Makefile to create those. Maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Regards,
Ariel

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Include `-g` in the flags sent to the compiler and linker. The default variables for this are `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` respectively.

The second step: exclude `-s` from flags (`-s` means **strip**)

Comment: The "-g" option only needs to be given to the compiler via the CFLAGS macro.  It's not necessary to have it in the LDFLAGS macro.

Comment: Cargo cult knowledge, I guess. At some point I used a linker that had to be told *not* to throw away the debugging symbols...

Answer (score 7):

If you are able to see source and set the breakpoint, then you probably have debugging symbols established.  However, the usual sequence is:

```
gcc -g -o (outputname) (source files...)
gdb outputname
```

Give more specifics about what you are doing and what messages you see and we can be more specific.

Answer (score 4):

The full example would be:

```
CFLAGS =-g

all: program.o
    gcc -o program program.o
```

The `CFLAGS` here is applied to both the compiler and the linker.

Comment: That's not true. In your example `-g` is only applied in the compile step. This is because compilation happens through an implicit rule of make that creates `program.o` from `program.c` (without `program.c` ever being mentioned explicitly in the makefile. The implicit rule uses `CFLAGS`. However, the explicit rule for the linking step is executed as shown - thus `-g` is *not* applied while linking (AFAIK it does not have to with gcc anyway).